# Image gallery pagination

Tags: javascript, image, pagination, gallery

I have created the following image gallery.

http://jsfiddle.net/sfiddle/Nf7yR/7/

I think the thing is, that even though I can get a hand on the paragraphs css, the currentIndex won't update, i.e. an event listener seems to be missing.

```
var thumb = document.getElementById("thumb");
myParagraphs = thumb.getElementsByTagName("p");

console.log(myParagraphs[1]);

function thumby(){
$(myParagraphs[currentIndex]).css("background-color", "red");
}

thumby();
```

The thing is that I can not manage to link the image index with the index of the pagination dot (which has a normal p tag).

I want to code it in that way that if the first picture is displayed the first dot is red, if the second image is displayed the second ...

How could I approach this?

Thanks for any good advice as I invested a few hours already but can not get my head around it.

PS: no, I want no plugin or ready made imagegallery, I want my approach to work :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a function `thumby()` but you are calling it only once (during script start). You just need to call it when you change `currentIndex`. Here you have fixed code: http://jsfiddle.net/Nf7yR/10/ (I commented my edits).

BTW your code looks terrible. You should indent it properly to make it easier to read :)

Comment: Hi ghost, works perfect. Actually I am pretty proud of myself that I only forgot two thumby() to call the functions. However, what do you mean by terrible. Terrible like: its only intendation (style) or terrible like in "what on earth are you coding?". I admit that I could have used jquery elemnts though. Regardless, now I try to code the opposite direction: clicking on a pagination button would change the image. Will shortly present my approaches if I don't manage it here in the forum. Best regards

Comment: Mostly about a style. But at least you know what you're doing and that's good. You will learn everything in good time. Good luck :)